# Help with change of variables in an integral

Tags: calculus

I couldn't get the following algebraic manipulations right.

Let $f $ be integrable on $[a, b ]$ and extend $f $ to take the value $f (b) $ on $(b, b+1 ] $.

Define Diff$ _h f(x)= \frac {f(x+h)-f(x) } {h }  $ and Av $ _hf(x)= \frac {1 } {h } \int _x ^{x+h } f $ for all $x \in [a, b ] $, $0<h \le 1 $

By change of variables in the integral and cancelation, show that for all $a \le u \le v \le b $

$\int _u ^v $Diff $ _h f=$Av $_h f(v)- $Av$ _h f(u)$

This should be straight forward. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting $t=x+h$ we have
$$\int_u^v f(x+h)\,dx=\int_{u+h}^{v+h} f(t)\,dt=\int_{u+h}^{v+h} f(x)\,dx\ .$$
Therefore
$$\eqalign{\int_u^v {\rm Diff}_hf
  &=\frac{1}{h}\int_{u+h}^{v+h} f(x)\,dx-\frac{1}{h}\int_u^v f(x)\,dx\cr
  &=\Bigl(\frac{1}{h}\int_{v}^{v+h} f(x)\,dx+\frac{1}{h}\int_{u+h}^{v} f(x)\,dx\Bigr)\cr
  &\qquad\qquad{}-\Bigl(\frac{1}{h}\int_{u+h}^v f(x)\,dx+\frac{1}{h}\int_u^{u+h} f(x)\,dx\Bigr)\cr
  &={\rm Av}_hf(v)-{\rm Av}_hf(v)\ .\cr}$$